# how to have two separate django sites that both use solr/jetty (hosted on webfaction)

Tags: django, solr, jetty, multicore, webfaction

I have one django site that is currently up and running with solr/jetty, hosted on webfaction.

Now I have a second site that I also use solr/jetty with, and I want to make sure I don't screw this up when I set it up on webfaction. I'm confused when I read the Solr docs - whether my setup would be a single instance with multicore, or if I need multiple instances?

I've read things about how if it is not set up correctly, that data from both sites will end up in the same index. They're completely separate sites in this case, so I don't want them to get mixed up.

When I set up the first site, I installed Solr/jetty under a custom app and have the django settings pointed to the port WF gave me. Could I just setup another custom app, install Solr/Jetty in it and point my second Django site to the new port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multicore would work fine. A multicore setup hosts several, completely separate indices in the same application server, and allows for separate configuration for each instance.

Reasons for not doing multicore but separate processes would be to allow one instance to survive if another runs out of memory, to load conflicting libraries into separate instances or something similar.

Unless you have very specific issues, go with a multicore setup. The multiple instance version was popular before multicore was even possible, but most setups today use multicore instead.